# Centos/MySQL Server Tweaking

Tags: mysql, centos

If I wanted a professional to like tweak my server where would I go about finding someone that does this? I have a web server that gets a lot of traffic and Im learning all about managing web servers, but before my traffic gets out of hand I want the server tweaked up. I already have some high load issues so I wanted to see if they could help with that. Then I would continue my learning on my own.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you **start** by learning as much as you can - then at least you'll be in a much stronger position to select candidates for the role. [Steve Souder's book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/High-Performance-Web-Sites-Essential/dp/0596529309) is an excellent place to start.

I'd also recommend you get hold of [mysqltuner](http://blog.mysqltuner.com/) which monitors your DBMS and makes specific suggestions of how to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

it's a little old but still relevant. This document really help me understand what the issues are.

http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

you don't say what your application is or what you use case is , so it's hard to give you any firm advice. However  think about separating static and dynamic content and using reverse proxies to share the load.

http://nginx.org/ may also help you server lots of content.

Your database server will need the same treatment.

I recommend you replicate you environment and setup on your own lan, thus you can try new configurations with out breaking you online web site.

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start, before sinking capital into professional services, is start with a mysql tuning script.

The one I regularly use is:
http://forge.mysql.com/projects/project.php?id=44

It will, at least, get your server to where it can be fine tuned.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically for sql index tuning. http://use-the-index-luke.com/